# How to copy React props data into the matrix avoiding infinite loop caused by setState in render()

Tags: reactjs

Please let me know how to get rid of the infinite loop in below example. I'm trying to copy the set of data from props into tab matrix to make some set of modifications.

```
class LoadPhrases extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tab: []
    };
  }

  render() {    

    let i=0;
    phrases = this.props.phrases.map(
      (ph)=>{
        var row = [i++, 0, ph.phrase1, ph.phrase2];
        var joined = this.state.tab.concat(row);
        this.setState({ tab: joined });
        return(
          <p></p>
        );
      }
    );

    return (   
      <div>
        Phrase:
        {this.state.tab[0][2]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into any of the lifecycle methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not use `phrases`, you could just:

```
class LoadPhrases extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tab: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let i=0;
    this.props.phrases.map(ph => {
        var row = [i++, 0, ph.phrase1, ph.phrase2];
        this.setState(prevState => ({ tab: [...prevState.tab.splice(prevState.tab.length, 0, row)] });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (   
      <div>
        Phrase:
        {this.state.tab.length > 0 && this.state.tab[0].length > 2 && this.state.tab[0][2]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to avoid the state entirely, and just display the desired content directly from `this.props`?

Comment: Yes it should be possible.

Comment: I get: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.tab[0].length')"

Comment: I do not know if my edit is working fine, but I didn't see that tab was an array of array. Could you try with my correction ?

Comment: I've just copy your code and I get this undefined error message. this.state.tab is just empty in render()

Comment: That's why we check for `this.state.tab.length > 0`.

Comment: Anyway componentDidMount() helped for the undefined loop Striped. Thx for that.

Comment: the full error message is: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.tab[0].length')>" when prerendering LoadPhrases with {"phrases": ... he can't even evaluate the length of undefined object. Something like setState didn't work.

Comment: I think the error is caused because render is called twice. For the first time the this.state.tab is undefined, but this condition '.length>0' is not working as expected

Comment: `this.state.tab` should not be undefined as you initialised it in the constructor. I'm not sure but I think that the component is rendering once the constructor has been called, right ?

Comment: Try to add `{this.state.tab &&  ...}` for testing purpose.

Comment: ok. I changed the condition to: `this.state.tab.length > 0?this.state.tab[0].row[2]:[]` and it works. Thank you Striped for a good path to solve the issue :)

Comment: Glad to help and congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're essentially doing this:

```js
const phrases = [
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_0_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_0_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_1_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_2_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_2_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_2_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_3_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_3_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_4_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_4_2",
  }
]

const LoadPhrases = props => {
  let state = {tab: []};

  props.phrases.map((ph, i) => {
    var row = [i, 0, ph.phrase1, ph.phrase2];
    state = { tab: [...state.tab, row] };
  });
 
  return (   
    <div>
      Phrase:
      {state.tab[0][2]}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<LoadPhrases phrases={phrases} />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Which means we should be able to access the `state.tab[0][2]` using `props[0].phrase1`, and avoid using any sort of state or `map()`. Like this:

```js
const phrases = [
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_0_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_0_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_1_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_2_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_2_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_2_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_3_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_3_2",
  },
  {
    phrase1: "phrase_4_1",
    phrase2: "phrase_4_2",
  }
]

const LoadPhrases = props => {
  return (   
    <div>
      Phrase:
      {props.phrases[0].phrase1}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<LoadPhrases phrases={phrases} />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: the thing is I want to dynamically add count: 0 to every object so avoiding modifying props I want to store them into tab variable.

Comment: Isn't the `count` the same as the index being displayed? For example, for `props.phrases[0].phrase1` the count is`0`. Likewise, for `props.phrases[5].phrase1` the count is `5`.

Comment: But in your example the `count` is just incremented on each iteration of  `map`?

Comment: [i++, 0, ph.phrase1, ph.phrase2] means for me [id, count, phrase1, phrase2] so in my case 0 is the initial count.

Comment: Ok, but it still never changes in the example. It's always `0`.

Comment: I've simplified it for better clarity. It's going to be changed once some event occurs. Just assume for now I will count clicks there :) I just want to copy props array of objects to some new array with 2 additional columns.